# Mutating value types in enumeration

Tags: swift, enumeration, value-type, mutation

Say we have

```
struct item {
  var val = 0
}

var items = [item]()
items.append(item(val: 0))
items.append(item(val: 1))
items.append(item(val: 2))
```

This code is obviously not possible since `i` is a `let` constant:

```
for i in items {
  i.val += 10
}
```

What works is this kinda of verbose loop:

```
for i in 0..<items.count {
  items[i].val += 10
}
```

and this map:

```
items = items.map { item(val:$0.val + 10) }
```

Both solutions don't look very "swifty" to me. Any ideas how to make them look better?

Also, I wonder what is the most performant way to accomplish this task (assuming `items` is a very large array)?

Comment: `for i in 0..<items.count` can be written as `for i in items.indices`

Comment: `items.indices.forEach { items[$0].val += 10 }`